# Firefox - "405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed" when loaded from selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I was trying to load a url in firefox using selenium webdriver. previously I was using FF ver.38.0.5 with selenium-java-2.46.0.jar and all was good. When I tried to upgrade the FF to ver 45.0.1 with selenium-java-2.53.1.jar the site previously loaded throws as 405 exception with error message as

```
405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
```

Kindly help me if anyone knows how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: If you're injecting data into a POST request that might be the issue, the website may need different data in the request depending on the browser you're using. Try using your old user-agent

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida No I m not injecting any data into a post, I just plainly call the url like `driver.get("http://test.xxxxx.com");`

one difference I saw is when I load from browser the request is going as **GET** but when I load it from webdriver the request is going as **POST** . I didnt do anything which forces the url to send request as POST. Is there any webdriver behaviour that will force POST in any circumstances??

Comment: Without knowing the url no one can reproduce the problem

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida I wish, but its customer's site :(

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this issue was created by an custom extension used in-house to do some datacollection.If we remove the extension and run the url its working fine. Thanks